# how can i retrieve image (blob type) from mysql to matlab with jpg type as original type?

Tags: mysql, matlab

I use a SQL query to retrieve image from MySQL database, I wish It comes with jpg type as original but, if I retrieve it from MySQL it comes with (unit8 type)!

the original image size is 280x320 and I try to convert it after I received it from MySQL with size {12323×1 uint8} and I got, Error using reshape To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change. image1=reshape(image,280,320);

Comment: Could you provide more details with what you have at the moment? Do you have the image loaded into MATLAB as a uint8 matrix? If so, just run `imwrite(your_image,'image_name.jpg','jpg')` where `your_image` is the name of the variable in MATLAB.

Comment: image = 1×1 cell array {12323×1 uint8}                                                                                      Error using imwrite (line 442)
Expected DATA to be one of these types:

numeric, logical

Instead its type was database.odbc.cursor.

Error in DB (line 6)
 imwrite(image,'image.jpg','jpg');

Comment: 12323x1 means the image has been reshaped into 1 long vector instead of a rectangular image. Do you know what size it should be? Also, could you edit the extra information into the question so others can help too?

Comment: the image size is 280x320 and I try to convert it Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change. image1=reshape(image,280,320);

Comment: This is an encoded JPEG stream, you need to decode it to obtain the pixels. There are utilities for this, for example here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53716-decodejpeg